# Typo3 iFrame Javascript not working inside Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, typo3

Domain of Typo3 (Version 4.3.3) Website: www.YYYY.com

The iFrame is pointing to this Domain: www.XXXX.com

Content of the iFrame Page: Javascript contactform based on jQuery

Inside TYPO3, I add an HTML content item with this code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.XXXX.com/share/?v=35" name="XXXX-com-35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="350" width="410"></iframe>
```

Everything works great in Firefox, Chrome and Safari Webbrowsers.

Only inside MS Internet Explorer (Version: 7, 8, 9, 10) I see the iFrame content but all the buttons an hyperlinks like "javascript:void(0);" are not working.

When I start the Devtools (F12) inside IE I see, that for all iFrame content scripts i get "Access denied".

I hope you have an answer on that. Thanks

Comment: If this was the solution for you, please add it as an answer, not as a question edit.

Comment: @Michael i did the change and added the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I used an old jQuery library (1.10.1)

With jQuery library (1.10.2) its now working. Looks like it was an jQuery bug.

I am now using:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And its wokring great on IE 7, 8, 9 and 10